# Получение постов со стены в VK через execute

Tags: vkontakte-api, vkscript

Пытаюсь получить все посты со стены в VK. Использую метод `execute`. Код метода:

```
var ITERS = 25;
var COUNT = 100;
var posts = [];
var req_params = {
        "owner_id" : Args.id,
        "offset" : 0,
        "count"  : COUNT,
        "v" : "5.34"
};
var i = 0;
while(i < ITERS){
    req_params.offset = i*COUNT + ITERS*COUNT*Args.offset;
    var response = API.wall.get(req_params);
    var items = response.items;

    if (items.length == 0) {
        return posts;
    }

    posts.push(items);
    i = i + 1;
}
return posts;
```

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: данный код возвращает список в `JSON` с постами, каждый из которых содержит поле `text` (текст поста). При получении, например, более 30000 постов с одной страницы, суммарный объем всех ответов составляет ~50MB (это много). Для решения проблемы решил изменить код метода, путём добавления в результирующий массив не весь объект поста, а только те его поля, которые мне нужны. Пример:

```
... // тут ничего не изменялось
while(i < ITERS){
    ... // тут тоже
    var j = 0;
    while (j < items.length){
        var tmp_item = {};
        tmp_item.id = items[j].id;
        tmp_item.date = items[j].date;
        tmp_item.likes = items[j].likes.count;
        tmp_item.reposts = items[j].reposts.count;
        posts.push(tmp_item);
        j = j+1;
    }

    // posts.push(items);
    i = i + 1;
}
return posts;
```

Но такой код не укладывается в лимит по количеству операций за один запрос. Если изменить `var COUNT` со `100` до `6`, то количество операций становится допустимым и суммарный размер всех ответов ~2MB, но работает такой код в два раза дольше.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: есть ли возможность получить все посты со стены без поля `text` за более или менее нормальное время?

**UPD** (спустя год). Эта штука работает и весьма неплохо: [VK-Top](https://github.com/yutkin/VK-Top).

Comment: А зачем вам за один раз все посты, если не секрет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Отсортировать посты по likes\reposts.

Comment: а если заменить несколько `items[j]` на один: `var itm = items[j];` и дальгше обращаться к `itm`, тоже превышается лимит запросов к API?

Comment: @Stack `Runtime error occurred during code invocation: Too many operations`, более того, если оставить во вложенном цикле только `posts.push(tmp_item)`, операций все равно слишком много.

Comment: если нужны только likes, то можно использовать специальный синтаксис для коллекций: `return API.wall.get(req_params)@.likes;`

Comment: @0x1337 Без поля `text` вряд ли возможно. На то этот метод и существует)) было бы бессмысленно возвращать пост....без поста)) Попробовать в цикле `count` оставить прежним 100, но повесить timeout (sleep) между запросами.

Comment: @Stack `return API.wall.get(req_params)@.likes;` возвращает `response: {
count: null,
items: null
}`.

Comment: @Stack вообще-то `return API.wall.get(req_params).items@.likes;` Но это не то, что хотел автор.

Comment: @0x1337 а можно пример стены где очень много записей? Возможно стоит попробовать более сложный запрос с использованием цикла `while` и формированием массива через `push` непосредственно в запросе к апи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я же и так в запросе API использую `while` и `push` (метод `execute` мой), пример стены с 30К+ записями `vk.com/tj`.

Comment: @0x1337 ммм. что-то я не сразу врубился.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проблему вроде как решил, с помощью `@.` оператора. Решение чуть позже опубликую.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский _"Но это не то, что хотел автор"_ -- но идея была понятна. и решение получено на основе `@`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно можно было сделать и лучше, но пока что придумал только так:

```
var ITERS = 25;
var COUNT = 100;
var posts = [];
var req_params = {
        "owner_id" : Args.id,
        "offset" : 0,
        "count"  : COUNT,
        "v" : "5.34"
};
var i = 0;
while(i < ITERS){
    req_params.offset = i*COUNT + ITERS*COUNT*Args.offset;
    var items = API.wall.get(req_params).items;

    if (items.length == 0) {
        return posts;
    }

    var ids = items@.id;
    var tmp = {};
    tmp.chunk_size = ids.length;
    tmp.ids = ids;
    tmp.likes = items@.likes@.count;
    tmp.reposts = items@.reposts@.count;
    tmp.dates = items@.date;
    posts.push(tmp);

    i = i + 1;
}
return posts;
```

Пример ответа:

```
response: [{
    chunk_size: 3,
    ids: [678032, 685909, 685908],
    likes: [1143, 154, 215],
    reposts: [95, 6, 11],
    dates: [1434489988, 1451844879, 1451840889]
}, {
    chunk_size: 3,
    ids: [685907, 685905, 685904],
    likes: [760, 493, 111],
    reposts: [48, 63, 1],
    dates: [1451833975, 1451831406, 1451827220]
}, {
    chunk_size: 3,
    ids: [685903, 685901, 685899],
    likes: [197, 486, 851],
    reposts: [11, 24, 56],
    dates: [1451823624, 1451818995, 1451815289]
}]
```

Время получения сократилось примерно на 20%, итоговый размер всех ответов сократился в среднем на 90%.

Comment: Да неплохо. Сам тоже уже хотел предложить вариант именно по частям)