# Вопрос по методу execute (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Не удаётся настроить запуск процедуры [execute](https://vk.com/dev/execute) (использован [первый код отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479670/), возвращающий 2500 постов из сообщества ВК) — согласно следующей конструкции:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/execute.posty_V_Tcikle
?owner_id=-29534144
&offset=0
&count=100
&extended=1
&v=5.71
&access_token=<TOKEN>
```

По её запуску почему-то приходят посты с привязанного к токену профиля, хотя если запускать процедуру по кнопке из интерфейса `execute` — команда отрабатывает.

Как её правильно записать в виде ссылки на процедуру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал более "хороший" код(мне он приятнее, по-крайней мере)

```
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
if(owner_id == null){
    return {"items": [], count: 0};
}
var offset = Args.offset;
if(offset == null) {
    offset = 0;
}

var count = Args.count;
if(count == null){
    count = 10;
}

var extended = Args.extended;
if(extended == null){
    extended = 0;
}

var filter = Args.filter;
if(filter == null){
    filter = "all";
}

var i = 0;
var items = [];

while(i < 25 && items.length < count){
    var cur_count = count - items.length;
    if(count - items.length > 100){
        cur_count = 100;
    }
    items = items + API.wall.get({"owner_id": owner_id, "offset": offset, "count": cur_count, "extended": extended, "filter": filter})["items"];
}

return {"items": items, "count": items.length};
```

Вызывать:
`https://api.vk.com/method/execute.posty_V_Tcikle
?owner_id=-29534144
&offset=0
&count=100
&extended=1
&v=5.71
&access_token=<TOKEN>`
Параметры `extended`, `count`, `offset` не обязательны.