# Получение информации о постах со стены ВКонтакта (настройка кода)

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Выше задавал похожий вопрос, но на этот раз требуется доработка практически готового варианта кода — подсказанного мне на другом ресурсе — под урезанный JS, принятый на VK API.
Сам код осуществляет получение информации о количестве лайков, репостов, комментариев, дат и айди — к до двух тысячам пяти ста постам указанного сообщества, который требуется настроить на работу с двумя сообществами. Это исходный вариант кода для работы с одним сообществом:

```
// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479670/ 
var ITERS = 1;     // до 25 итераций 
var COUNT = 100;   // до 100 постов за 1 итерацию 
var posts = []; 
var req_params = { 
        "owner_id" : Args.id, 
        "offset" : 0, 
        "count"  : COUNT, 
        "v" : "5.34" 
}; 
var i = 0; 
while(i < ITERS){ 
    req_params.offset = i*COUNT + ITERS*COUNT*Args.offset; 
    var items = API.wall.get(req_params).items; 

    if (items.length == 0) { 
        return posts; 
    } 

    var ids = items@.id; 
    var tmp = {}; 
    //tmp.chunk_size = ids.length; 
    tmp.ids = ids; 
    //tmp.likes = items@.likes@.count; 
    //tmp.reposts = items@.reposts@.count; 
    //tmp.comments = items@.comments@.count; 
    //tmp.dates = items@.date; 
    posts.push(tmp); 

    i = i + 1; 
} 
return posts;
```

А ниже — подсказанный мне вариант, который должен получать инфу одновременно с двух стен (чтобы в одном сообщении приходило два массива с сотней айди к двум разным сообществам), но который в урезанном формате ВК АПИ не отрабатывает, и поэтому задача подладить его к их серверному JS, в чём и прошу посодействовать:

```
var listz = ["-29534144", "-125004421"];
var ITERS = 1;        // до 25 итераций    
var COUNT = 100;   // до 100 постов за 1 итерацию    
var posts = [];    
var j = 0; 
while(j < listz.length) {  
var req_params = {    
        "owner_id" : listz[j],      
        "offset" : 0,    
        "count"  : COUNT,    
        "v" : "5.34"    
};    
var i = 0;    
while(i < ITERS){    
    req_params.offset = i*COUNT + ITERS*COUNT*Args.offset;    
    var items = API.wall.get(req_params).items;    

    if (items.length == 0) {    
        return posts;    
    }    

    var ids = items@.id;    
    var tmp = {};    
    tmp.ids = ids;    
    posts[listz[j]].push(tmp);    

    i = i + 1;    
} 
j = j + 1; 
}  
return posts;
```

Comment: А первый вариант изначального кода отрабатывает себя?

Comment: Да, он рабочий.

Comment: лучше выполнять это в 2 запроса